# Can I get encrypt and decrypt algorithm that's more varied than what I have?

Tags: c#

This is the one I  currently used

The problem is I am seeing pattern. For example,

```
/4mbvuxjWEZnXjO/mzjQhAmcA3lGwohhTxwcx3Tvcx5Ax5HThO2KJGKZ9B1luwabKBSuYBwDcFdp4VO1BgIRXTg/yfvt9pZAc45ebUeFQmuI3xcPluwgh9DR+uqekqdO

/4mbvuxjWEZnXjO/mzjQhBOlj2wiF10gXJOFrqmOZ6zeseuSExCrcdDs1pABE+J4WTynWBqO7sCkIXWo0DwnMD4saXqy3hyl7u/cthd2ZNY7bj7m1KbcdMwLVcT9bet9Wj9rJspQAiFAvCHx/NevSQ==

/4mbvuxjWEZnXjO/mzjQhBOlj2wiF10gXJOFrqmOZ6zeseuSExCrcdDs1pABE+J4WTynWBqO7sCkIXWo0DwnME8zI4EUdapiqGlsluJq2Me/R/5P4OV6a/45GwtG2CuRPAM5DVDP8EY5ZflQACXtpA==
```

All enscrypted URL start with `/4mbvuxjWEZnXjO/mzjQhBOlj2wiF10gXJOFrqmOZ6zeseuSExCrcdDs1pABE+J4WTynWBqO7`

Well, I want encryption without that pattern.

This is the code I am currently using.

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    string passPhrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"];
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}

private const string initVector = "i51K0t4k4yAraY48";

// This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm.
private const int keysize = 128;

public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    string passPhrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"];
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string passPhrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"];
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

Comment: "I want encryption without that pattern." - then vary the `initVector`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the same key and the same [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) to encrypt very similar strings. This will tend to create similar ciphertext, as you have seen. Vary one or the other.

If you cannot do that (for whatever reason), you could create a few cryptographically random bytes and append them to each URL before encryption and discard them after decryption. Since AES with CBC has a reasonable [avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) for subsequent blocks, this should remove the patterns you are observing.

As an aside, I think the code may have some potential issues. You are mixing ASCII and UTF8 encoding between both `Encrypt` and the single `Decrypt` functions. You also should be using `try`/`finally` or `using` blocks to ensure the `IDisposable` implementing classes are cleaned up properly if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very nice library called Cryptsharp. They have many algoritms you can choose from, and they are very easy to use. You can install using nuget

Project page

https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/cryptsharp

the nuget package

http://www.nuget.org/packages/CryptSharp/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my CryptoClass, you can easily call the constructor with password and iVString. After that you have an encryption without pattern if you change at least one value. You can easily manage a routine to use some iVString and avoid to change password.

hope it helps.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace iOSEncryption
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a simple interface for Symmetric Criptography using Rijndael algorithm 
    /// </summary>
    public class CryptoRijndael
    {
        public static Byte[] DefaultSalt
        {
            get
            {
                return defaultSalt;
            }
        }
        private static Byte[] defaultSalt = new Byte[24] 
        { 
            0x6d, 0x61, 0x79, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x66, 0x6f, 
            0x72, 0x63, 0x65, 0x62, 0x65, 0x77, 0x69, 0x74, 
            0x68, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x4a, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69 
        };

        private static Byte[] GetRandomArray(Int32 length)
        {
            Byte[] retVal = new Byte[length];
            Random rd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                retVal[i] = (Byte)rd.Next(0x0, 0xFF);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
            return retVal;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents an array of Bytes to derives Private Key and IV
        /// </summary>
        public class Salt
        {
            private Byte[] _Value = null;
            public Byte[] Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Value;
                }
            }

            public Salt()
                : this(defaultSalt)
            {

            }
            public Salt(Byte[] value)
            {
                if (value.Length < 16)
                {
                    throw new InvalidSaltLengthException();
                }
                else
                {
                    _Value = value;
                }
            }

            public class InvalidSaltLengthException : Exception
            {
                public InvalidSaltLengthException()
                    : base("Bytes array must contains at least 16 elements")
                {

                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents an array of 32 bytes. 
        /// A consistent 256 bits private Key
        /// </summary>
        public class PrivateKey
        {
            private Byte[] _Value = null;
            public Byte[] Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Value;
                }
            }

            public PrivateKey()
                : this(GetRandomArray(32))
            {

            }
            public PrivateKey(Byte[] value)
            {
                if (value.Length != 32)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPrivateKeyLengthException();
                }
                else
                {
                    _Value = value;
                }
            }

            public class InvalidPrivateKeyLengthException : Exception
            {
                public InvalidPrivateKeyLengthException()
                    : base("Bytes array must contains 32 elements")
                {

                }
            }

            public class InvalidPrivateKeyException : Exception
            {
                public InvalidPrivateKeyException()
                    : base("Private key must be valid and not null")
                {

                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the initializion vector for the simmetric algorithm
        /// </summary>
        public class InitVector
        {
            private Byte[] _Value = null;
            public Byte[] Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Value;
                }
            }

            public InitVector()
                : this(GetRandomArray(16))
            {

            }
            public InitVector(Byte[] value)
            {
                if (value.Length != 16)
                {
                    throw new InvalidIVLengthException();
                }
                else
                {
                    _Value = value;
                }
            }

            public class InvalidIVLengthException : Exception
            {
                public InvalidIVLengthException()
                    : base("Bytes array must contains 16 elements")
                {

                }
            }
        }

        public class DecryptException : Exception
        {
            public DecryptException(Exception innerException) :
                base("Decrypt error occurred check for Password, PrivateKey, IV or Salt", innerException)
            {

            }
        }
        public class EncryptException : Exception
        {
            public EncryptException(Exception innerException) :
                base("Encrypt error occurred", innerException)
            {

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the 256 bits private Key for the simmetric algorithm
        /// </summary>
        public PrivateKey ActivePrivateKey { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current array of Bytes for derives Key and IV from a given password
        /// </summary>
        public Salt ActiveSalt { get; private set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current IV for the simmetric algorithm
        /// </summary>
        public InitVector ActiveIV { get; private set; }


        private Encoding _StringEncodingType = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the EncodingType. Default is 1252
        /// </summary>
        public Encoding StringEncodingType
        {
            get
            {
                return _StringEncodingType;
            }
            set
            {
                _StringEncodingType = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new istance of the CryptoRijndael class.\r\n
        /// Creates randoms privateKey and IV.
        /// </summary>
        public CryptoRijndael()
        {
            ActivePrivateKey = new PrivateKey();
            ActiveIV = new InitVector();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new istance of the CryptoRijndael class.\r\n
        /// privateKey must be Byte[32] and initVector must be Byte[16]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="privateKey"></param>
        /// <param name="initVector"></param>
        public CryptoRijndael(Byte[] privateKey, Byte[] initVector)
        {
            ActivePrivateKey = new PrivateKey(privateKey);
            ActiveIV = new InitVector(initVector);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new istance of the CryptoRijndael class.\r\n
        /// Derives 256bits private Key from password and IV from iVString using Byte[24] default Salt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        public CryptoRijndael(String password, String iVString)
        {
            ActiveSalt = new Salt(defaultSalt);
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes dbKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, ActiveSalt.Value);
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes dbIV = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(iVString, ActiveSalt.Value);
            ActivePrivateKey = new PrivateKey(dbKey.GetBytes(32));
            ActiveIV = new InitVector(dbIV.GetBytes(16));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new istance of the CryptoRijndael class.\r\n
        /// Derives 256bits private Key and IV form password using Byte[24] default Salt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        public CryptoRijndael(String password)
            : this(password, defaultSalt)
        {

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new istance of the CryptoRijndael class.\r\n
        /// Derives 256bits private Key and IV form password using custom Salt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="salt"></param>
        public CryptoRijndael(String password, Byte[] salt)
        {
            ActiveSalt = new Salt(salt);
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes db = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, ActiveSalt.Value);
            ActivePrivateKey = new PrivateKey(db.GetBytes(32));
            ActiveIV = new InitVector(db.GetBytes(16));
        }

        public void Encrypt(Stream clearData, Stream encryptedData)
        {
            EncryptException ee = null;
            if (ActivePrivateKey == null)
            {
                throw new PrivateKey.InvalidPrivateKeyException();
            }
            else
            {
                Rijndael alg = null;
                CryptoStream cs = null;
                try
                {
                    alg = Rijndael.Create();


                    alg.Key = ActivePrivateKey.Value;
                    alg.IV = ActiveIV.Value;

                    cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedData, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                    clearData.CopyTo(cs);

                    cs.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ee = new EncryptException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cs != null)
                    {
                        cs.Dispose();
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(cs);
                        cs = null;
                    }

                    if (alg != null)
                    {
                        alg.Dispose();
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(alg);
                        alg = null;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (ee != null)
            {
                throw ee;
            }
        }

        public void Decrypt(Stream clearData, Stream encryptedData)
        {

            DecryptException de = null;
            if (ActivePrivateKey == null)
            {
                throw new PrivateKey.InvalidPrivateKeyException();
            }
            else
            {
                Rijndael alg = null;
                CryptoStream cs = null;
                try
                {
                    alg = Rijndael.Create();


                    alg.Key = ActivePrivateKey.Value;
                    alg.IV = ActiveIV.Value;

                    cs = new CryptoStream(clearData, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    encryptedData.CopyTo(cs);
                    cs.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    de = new DecryptException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cs != null)
                    {
                        cs.Dispose();
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(cs);
                        cs = null;
                    }

                    if (alg != null)
                    {
                        alg.Dispose();
                        GC.SuppressFinalize(alg);
                        alg = null;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (de != null)
            {
                throw de;
            }
        }

        public Byte[] Encrypt(Byte[] clearData)
        {
            Byte[] encryptedData = null;
            MemoryStream encms = new MemoryStream();
            MemoryStream clms = new MemoryStream(clearData);

            Encrypt(clms, encms);

            encryptedData = encms.ToArray();

            encms.Close();
            encms.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(encms);
            encms = null;

            clms.Close();
            clms.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(clms);
            clms = null;

            return encryptedData;
        }

        public Byte[] Decrypt(Byte[] encryptedData)
        {
            Byte[] clearData = null;
            MemoryStream encms = new MemoryStream(encryptedData);
            MemoryStream clms = new MemoryStream();

            Decrypt(clms, encms);

            clearData = clms.ToArray();

            encms.Close();
            encms.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(encms);
            encms = null;

            clms.Close();
            clms.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(clms);
            clms = null;

            return clearData;
        }

        public String Encrypt(String clearData)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(StringEncodingType.GetBytes(clearData)));
        }

        public String Decrypt(String encryptedData)
        {
            return StringEncodingType.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData)));
        }


    }
}
```